# Is there a way to change the order of the job queue in Jenkins?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

We are using Jenkins to export animations in Maya, and we would like to change the order of the jobs that are waiting in the queue. For example, make one of the jobs in the queue to be the next to run (at the end of the one in progress)

Is this possible in Jenkins?
Thanks!

Comment: Check out the [Priority Sorter Plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/PrioritySorter/)